# Python - can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 4: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python

I have the following string:

`cbBb’`

the last character is `u'\u2019'`.

I tried the following:

```
value = "cbBb’"
value.replace(u"\u2019", "-")
value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

but then when i try to do:

```
str(value)
```

I get:

```
can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 4: ordinal not in range(256)
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: What version of Python are you running? And what are the backticks in line one supposed to mean?

Comment: It works in Python 3, but you aren't reassigning your `replace()` call (since it's not an inline function)...

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: `value = "cbBb’"` is already a `str` in Python 2.7, plus it is a syntax error to have a non-ASCII character in a Python 2 script without a source encoding declared, e.g. `#coding:utf8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python 2 strings can be unicode or just regular strings. you should specify it's a unicode string to run your `replace()` by adding a `u` infront of the string

```
value = u'cbBb’'
value = value.replace(u"\u2019", "-")
value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print(str(value)) #cbBb-
```

Also `replace()` isn't in line and you need to reassign it to something.

---

Side note you might want to consider swapping to Python 3 since unicode handling in Python 2 is a bit mucky.

Comment: Thanks, i think my biggest mistake was not realizing `replace` wasn't inline.